# PyQt5. QTextEdit

Tags: python, qt5

Как мне получить текст из поля QTextEdit, и как мне его вывести туда?

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста свой пример, где вы используете виджет QTextEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, у `Qt` по `QTextEdit` есть документация: http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextedit.html

---

По ней вы узнаете, что у `QTextEdit` есть два метода получения текст:

- [QTextEdit::toPlainText()](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText) - возвращает просто текст
- [QTextEdit::toHtml()](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop) - возвращает HTML, описывающий текст. Полезно, когда в тексте есть всякое форматирование: выделение, таблицы, списки, и т.п.

---

Так что:

```
te = QTextEdit()
te.setPlaintText('123')
print(te.toPlainText())
```

и

```
te = QTextEdit()
te.setHtml('<b>1</b>2<br>3')
print(te.toHtml())
```

Comment: Если помогло, [проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Или оставьте свой ответ :)